# Uniquely determining linear operators on finite field extensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations, extension-field

My current question asks me to prove the following:

Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension. Let $\phi: K \rightarrow K$ be $F$-linear.

**Prove the following statement:**

> If $K = F(\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_n)$, then $\phi$ is determined by its
>   action on $\{\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n\}$.

An earlier part of the problem involves proving that if $p(x) \in F[x]$ has a root $\alpha \in K$, then $\phi(\alpha)$ is also a root of $p(x)$, which is much easier.

I know that from linear algebra, the linear transformation $\phi$ is uniquely determined by its action on the basis, but the basis in this case is a set of products of the $\alpha_i$, not $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$ .

Furthermore, we cannot assert that $\phi$ is multiplicative (i.e. $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$) since left-multiplication by scalars does not satisfy this property, and yet is a linear transformation.

Can anybody please offer me a solution or at least a hint? I would sincerely appreciate some help.

Comment: @EBO from Dummit and Foote Sec. 13.2, the set of products $\alpha_1^{i_1}\ldots\alpha_n^{i_n}$, where there are restrictions on the powers of the $\alpha_j$, form a basis for $F(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)$. I tried using this earlier as noted, but got nowhere with it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got it wrong at first... There's something not ok... If we take $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, we have $\{1,\sqrt2\}$ as a basis for $K/F$. Put $T\colon K\rightarrow K$ as $T(a+b\sqrt2)=a$, which is clearly $F$-linear. Then $\sqrt2$ is a root of $x^2-2$ but $T(\sqrt2)=0$ is not.

Comment: Are you sure $\phi$ isn't an $F$-linear field automorphism?  Because then everything flies.

Comment: @EBO you are right. In my derivation of the earlier result, I mistakenly assumed that $\phi$ was also a ring homomorphism, which returns the correct result. I think my professor must have forgotten to proofread when he posted this problem, which has confounded me and my classmates for several days.

Comment: @RobertLewis it is likely that $\phi$ was intended to be an $F$-linear automorphism and that the creator of the document simply forgot to mention that among the hypotheses...

Comment: I may attempt an answer under that hypothesis.  Cheers!

Comment: Whoops! Posted by accident way too early.  Stay tuned . . .

Comment: Agree with 2017Algebraist. An $F$-automorphism is determined by the choice of images of field generators, but a mere $F$-linear mapping is not.